# does the sintaxys in AppsScript has changed?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

hi good day I’ve been working in AppsScript (you know the script editor of google) and i was following a tutorial to fill a google docs from google sheets, in it, the guy explains that he use var.getBody().replaceText() just like this:

```
Docs.getBody().replaceText({{name}}, name);
```

Where Docs is a variable, {{name}} is the pattern that is going to be replaced in google docs and name is another variable now my problem is that when i write the pattern ({{name}}) a wild pop up appears saying "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' " so my question is: does the syntax in AppsScript has changed? or what can i do? help please... thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are supposed to be strings so they need quotation marks: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replaceText(String,String)

Answer (score 0):

Apps Script uses JavaScript as it's programming language. The line that you added is not valid JavaScript, hence the error. Like Cooper said, you probably forgot the quotation marks:

```js
Docs.getBody().replaceText("{{name}}", name)
```

### References

- [Overview of Google Apps Script (Apps Script guide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)
- [JavaScript (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)
- [Body.replaceText(searchPattern, replacement) (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement)